# How to read keys from jSON

Tags: objective-c

how to print the key `event_id` on label.

```
"all_data" =     (
            {
        "company_logo" = "http://mbdbtechnology.com/projects/officeapp/uploads/event/Voxev\U00e6rket_logo_stort.png";
        "event_id" = 8;
        "event_name" = "Dit nye kontor i Voxev\U00e6rket";
        "event_sort_desc" = "Voxev\U00e6rket tilbyder landsd\U00e6kkende kontorer til ny opstartede";
    },
            {
        "company_logo" = "http://mbdbtechnology.com/projects/officeapp/uploads/event/Image_jpg_2_288X200.jpg";
        "event_id" = 7;
        "event_name" = "Sunday Special only for women";
        "event_sort_desc" = "Declarations of war At midnight on 31 July \U2013 1 Aug, French 2";
    },
```

Comment: You need to take whatever your question is out of the title, clarify it, and include it in the body of the question. Use the edit link under your question to achieve this.

Comment: have you parsed the jSON. show us what you have already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
 //responseData is an NSData object containing the jSON

NSMutableArray *allData = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"all_data"];

for (NSDictionary* dict in allData)
{
  NSString *eventID = [dict objectForKey:@"event_id"];
  NSLog(@"event ID : %@",eventID);
}
```